# Simple postgresql Insert/Update queries taking *seconds* to respond every 5-7 minutes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Ruby on Rails app that is using a Postgresql database. I've noticed that my database performance has huge spikes every 5-7 minutes.

[image: newrelic request response time - database spikes]

I'm seeing 1+ second response times for simple queries like:

```
UPDATE users SET last_seen_at = ? where id = ?
```

or

```
INSERT INTO emails (email, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

The VPS is an AWS EC2 instance (m2.2xlarge) with a 4 core Xeon 2.4ghz and 34gb of memory.

[Here is my postgresql.conf](https://gist.github.com/joshm1/3170215b77898583e4ce)

I made to following changes to the conf to try to figure it out (like reducing the # of checkpoint timeouts) to no avail.

```
root:/etc/postgresql/9.2/main# diff postgresql.conf.bck postgresql.conf
176,178c176,178
< #checkpoint_segments = 3    # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
< #checkpoint_timeout = 5min    # range 30s-1h
< #checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
---
> checkpoint_segments = 10    # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
> checkpoint_timeout = 30min    # range 30s-1h
> checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
361c361
< #log_min_duration_statement = -1  # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
---
> log_min_duration_statement = 2s  # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
370,371c370,371
< #debug_print_rewritten = off
< #debug_print_plan = off
---
> #debug_print_rewritten = on
> #debug_print_plan = on
376c376
< #log_duration = off
---
> #log_duration = on
378c378
< #log_hostname = off
---
> #log_hostname = on
399c399
< #log_lock_waits = off     # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
---
> log_lock_waits = on     # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
```

Comment: What indexes are you using? Constraints? FKs?

Comment: One table that is resulting in 1+ seconds response time for INSERTs only has an index on the PK ("id") and no other constraints.  There are other tables with no constraints/indexes other than the PK that have bad insert/update performance as well.  The query on the "users" table that updates the "last_seen_at" column only conditions by the "id" column, which, of course, is the PK.

Comment: @joshm1 . . . Do you have any jobs scheduled to run on the server in 5-minute intervals?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no I don't, this was one of the first things I checked. I even disabled all cron jobs and noticed this was still happening.  Also, the database runs on a different VPS from the web app.

Comment: turn `log_checkpoints=on`, lower `log_min_duration_statement=250ms` or something like that, and compare when the occurrence of slow statements to the occurrence of checkpoints.  Also, see what the time taken to sync the files on checkpoint is.

Comment: @jjanes here's what i have from the first checkpoint complete, and all logged "slow" queries before that: https://gist.github.com/joshm1/84b481602dbd0593c493

Comment: Perhaps you have connections that aren't closed? And what tool did you use to generate the graph?

Comment: @hd1 NewRelic for the graph. And it doesn't look like I have any unclosed connections. When I checked there were only 12, which are all from application servers.

Answer (score 1):

You have a serious IO problem at the end of the checkpoints.  Note that the slow queries are mostly COMMIT, which should do almost nothing but flush the WAL log, and that it took 41.604 s to sync the files (including 11 s to sync one file!).

There is probably nothing much you can do from within PostgreSQL to improve this.  I've heard rumors that lowering shared_buffers might help, but I have not seen that first hand.

You probably need to make changes on the operating system, like lowering `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` so that it doesn't allow so much dirty data to build up between checkpoints.  Also, if you can separate your WAL logs to separate disks from the main data, that can help.

What filesystem are you using?  What kernel/distro?

There is also the possibility that your workload simply can't be accommodated by the IO system you are using, and you need to move to more capable hardware.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Linux 3.2.0 x86_64). Filesystem is either ext3 or ext4. I don't remember and not sure how to check from CLI.  Regarding the workload/IO, the hardware should be plenty (if not excessive). This is not a database for a high volume sites, so it's not like it is getting hundreds of queries a second (ideally, I should know exactly how much it is getting, but I don't have those metrics yet). I will take a look into your suggestions and post my findings.

Comment: I don't see spikes as large as what I originally posted but the overall performance didn't change when I set dirty_ratio and dirty_background_ratio in half (20/10 to 10/5). There is still an abundance of simple insert/updates taking a very long time: duration: 9803.873 ms  statement COMMIT; duration: 7182.702 ms  statement: COMMIT;
duration: 7330.457 ms  statement: COMMIT

Comment: @joshm1 you can check your filesystem type with "df -T".  Your checkpoint had a sync 338 different files, which is a lot.  Perhaps your site is higher volume than you realize--for example, having a lot of indexes on a table will generate a lot of IO whenever the table is inserted or updated.

Comment: @joshm1 With 34GB of RAM, A dirty_background_ratio of 5 is still a large amount of dirty RAM.  You might want to lower it further, and switch to dirty_background_bytes to give you finer control.  You also might want to do some low level IO benchmarking of your system., especially with random (as opposed to sequential) writes.  I've heard bad rumors about the performance of AWS on disk IO, but have no direct experience myself.

Comment: Depending on the number of writes, that may not be enough segments (or max_wal_size nowadays). You can tell if you're getting checkpoints in less than checkpoint_timeout time. You can also try pushing checkpoint_completion_target higher - I've had it all the way up to 1.0, and it helped.